# Extract values after match a keyword

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to extract values after I match the keyword "coor" multiple times in a string. My code doesn't do that at all. Can anyone help me to fix it please?

My code:

```
my $str = ;
if ($str =~ /$keyword/)
{
  if ($' =~ /\[/) #'# everything after the matched string
  {
    $str=~ /\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s/;
    {
      open( my $file, '>>', $filename );
      print {$file} $1, " ";
      print {$file} $2, " ";
      print {$file} $3, " ";
      print {$file} $4, " ";
      print {$file} $5, " ";
      print {$file} $6, " ";
      print {$file} $7, " ";
      print {$file} $8, " ";
      close( $file );
    }
  }
}
```

This is my input string:

```
[(beginKey object1 (coor 141 257) (coor 1315 254) (coor 1313 430) (coor 140 420) [] [] []), (beginKey keyword (coor 2035 253) (coor 1315 254) (coor 1313 430) (coor 2034 436) [] [] [])].
```

Comment: Hi Balpha.

Yes. The aim is to extract the 8 values after "keyword", because there other values before "keyword". Thank you.

Comment: I had already delete my comment again; never mind.

Comment: Please show an example of the text you are trying to parse

Comment: It would help a lot if you could show example values, because as it is now, we can only guess what kind of input you really want to match.

Comment: I've posted an example of data. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the code to be more maintainable, but left the regex alone because that was the whole point of this question. It still does exactly what it did before. The main reason I did this, is someone might come along, and copy it, and I didn't want them to copy something that could be considered, by some, to be sub-par. For more information you could read "Perl Best Practices" http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=%22Perl%20best%20practices%22

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl's `\G` anchor in scalar context is useful in this case because it continues where a previous `//g` match left off:

```
if (/keyword/g) {
  my @coor;

  while (/\G\s*\(coor (\d+) (\d+)\)/g) {
    push @coor => [$1, $2];
  }

  for (@coor) {
    print "@$_\n";
  }
}
```

With `$_` set to your sample input, the code above outputs

```
2035 253
1315 254
1313 430
2034 436
```

Comment: Also, much more concise and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the special characters in the regex:

```
(coor (1) (2)) => \(coor (1) (2)\)
```

same for /[/ that is a syntax error => /[/

Here is my modified version of your script, the regex is fixed, I split the string on ',' to match the intended keyword and the regex result is tested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $keyword = "object1";
my $str = "[(beginKey object1 (coor 141 257) (coor 1315 254) (coor 1313 430) (coor 140 420) [] [] []), (beginKey keyword (coor 2035 253) (coor 1315 254) (coor 1313 430) (coor 2034 436) [] [] [])].";
my @entries=split(',', $str);
foreach my $entry (@entries)
{
  if ($entry =~ /$keyword/)
  {
    my $tomatch=$';
    if ($tomatch =~ /\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s\(coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\)\s/)
    {
      print $1," ";
      print $2," ";
      print $3," ";
      print $4," ";
      print $5," ";
      print $6," ";
      print $7," ";
      print $8," ";
    }
    else
    {
      print "no match !";
    }
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
141 257 1315 254 1313 430 140 420
```

Answer (score 0):

[ is a special character inside a regex, so your second match needs to be against `/\[/` to match a literal [.

Your third match has 12 sets of capturing parentheses; I'm guessing you want `/coor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\scoor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\scoor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\scoor\s(\d+)\s(\d+)/` instead.  You also should check that the match succeeded before using $1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't see a problem with your current code.

offtopic: in Qt, QRegExp has a method int MatchedLength() - very easy to see how much of your string was matched.